# Cancelling UV divergences with IR divergences

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

My main question is the following: Are there certain QFT's in which for all Feynman diagrams the UV divergences cancel the IR divergences, leaving only a finite result for each diagram.

While searching for an example, I stumbled upon [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102707/renormalizing-ir-and-uv-divergences), but the example provided there was too specific. Are there other QFT's that you know of that has this interesting property?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by UV divergences cancelling IR divergences? This is a phenomenon that is renormalization-scheme dependent so it is unphysical, it doesn't tell you anything about the theory under consideration, it is not an intrinsic property. Furthermore, a regulator that does this is usually considered a bad one, because UV divergences are unphysical (they come from unobservable heavy modes) while IR divergences are very physical (they come from observable, macroscopic modes).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Have you looked at the question I have referenced?

Comment: Yes, I have.${}$